# Random Forest gets 98% accuracy in training and testing but always predicts the same class otherwise

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, imbalanced-data

I have spent 30 hours on this single problem de-bugging and it makes absolutely no sense, hopefully one of you guys can show me a different perspective.

The problem is that I use my training dataframe in a random forest and get very good accuracy 98%-99% but when I try and load in a new sample to predict on. The model ALWAYS guesses the same class.

```
#  Shuffle the data-frames records. The labels are still attached
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

#  Extract the labels and then remove them from the data
y = list(df['label'])
X = df.drop(['label'], axis='columns')

#  Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=TEST_SIZE)

#  Construct the model
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=N_ESTIMATORS, max_depth=MAX_DEPTH, random_state=RANDOM_STATE,oob_score=True)

#  Calculate the training accuracy
in_sample_accuracy = model.fit(X_train, y_train).score(X_train, y_train)
#  Calculate the testing accuracy
test_accuracy = model.score(X_test, y_test)

print()
print('In Sample Accuracy: {:.2f}%'.format(model.oob_score_ * 100))
print('Test Accuracy: {:.2f}%'.format(test_accuracy * 100))
```

The way I am processing the data is the same, but when I predict on the X_test or X_train I get my normal 98% and when I predict on my new data it always guesses the same class.

```
    #  The json file is not in the correct format, this function normalizes it
    normalized_json = json_normalizer(json_file, "", training=False)
    #  Turn the json into a list of dictionaries which contain the features
    features_dict = create_dict(normalized_json, label=None)

    #  Convert the dictionaries into pandas dataframes
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(features_dict)
    print('Total amount of email samples: ', len(df))
    print()

    df = df.fillna(-1)
    #  One hot encodes string values
    df = one_hot_encode(df, noOverride=True)
    if 'label' in df.columns:
        df = df.drop(['label'], axis='columns')
    print(list(model.predict(df))[:100])
    print(list(model.predict(X_train))[:100])
```

Above is my testing scenario, you can see in the last two lines I am predicting on `X_train` the data used to train the model and `df` the out of sample data that it always guesses class 0.

Some useful information:

- The datasets are imbalanced; class 0 has about 150,000 samples while class 1 has about 600,000 samples
- There are 141 features
- changing the n_estimators and max_depth doesn't fix it

Any ideas would be helpful, also if you need more information let me know my brain is fried right now and that's all I could think of.

Comment: couple of question that are not answered in the OP. 1. Have you applied any measure to treat the imbalanced data before training the model? 2. Has the data been randomly sampled before training the models? 3. Has cross-validation been applied before building the model?

Comment: @mnm So the model originally worked a few days ago and predicted things accurately even without balancing the data so I made no attempt. The data was randomly sampled and I've even tried re-processing and predicting on samples that were used in training which ended up guessing the same class every time

Comment: Could you please check if `df` is filled out correctly? Maybe it's all -1's after `df=df.fillna(-1)`? Just a guess.

Comment: Accuracy is not so good for imbalnced data as it guides the model towards predicting correctly on majority class. You need to either (1) resample data so that classes are more or less evenly reperesented (2) weight classes (3) choose more robust metrics like AUC or f1

Comment: @DL_Engineer as per the OP, the class 1 is 4 times greater than class 0 so its quite possible initially the model was working only for class 1. Try building a new model using ROC AUC  as an evaluation metric.

Comment: @kate-melnykova I have checked, I am using pycharm IDE to debug so I can visualize the dataframe, all the numbers in there look good and exactly like my training set. mnm sergey-bushmanov I have calculated precision, recall and F1 which all show accuracy of training set is in the high 90's. For sergey-bushmanov how would I assign weights to the classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, The issue was the imbalance of datasets also I realized that changing the depth gave me different results.

For example, 10 trees with 3 depth -> seemed to work fine
10 trees with 6 depth -> back to guessing only the same class